# Docker daemon service crash very often on worker node

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, linux-kernel, docker-swarm

Docker service stops very often on one of my remote worker node.

I am not able to figure out why this is happening?

OS: Ubuntu 19.04

** Log: journelctl -xe**

```
Mar 12 10:43:44 machine1 systemd-networkd[434]: vethc827a75: Gained IPv6LL
Mar 12 10:43:44 machine1 kernel: docker_gwbridge: port 2(veth7e595dc) entered disabled state
Mar 12 10:43:45 machine1 kernel: docker_gwbridge: port 3(veth7574e8b) entered blocking state
Mar 12 10:43:45 machine1 kernel: docker_gwbridge: port 3(veth7574e8b) entered forwarding state
Mar 12 10:43:45 machine1 kernel: veth2: renamed from veth3b5a70d
Mar 12 10:43:45 machine1 kernel: br0: port 4(veth2) entered blocking state
Mar 12 10:43:45 machine1 kernel: br0: port 4(veth2) entered disabled state
Mar 12 10:43:45 machine1 kernel: device veth2 entered promiscuous mode
Mar 12 10:43:45 machine1 kernel: br0: port 4(veth2) entered blocking state
Mar 12 10:43:45 machine1 kernel: br0: port 4(veth2) entered forwarding state
Mar 12 10:43:45 machine1 kernel: br0: port 3(veth1) entered disabled state
Mar 12 10:43:45 machine1 kernel: docker_gwbridge: port 3(veth7574e8b) entered disabled state
Mar 12 10:43:45 machine1 kernel: br0: port 4(veth2) entered disabled state
Mar 12 10:43:45 machine1 kernel: docker_gwbridge: port 4(vethcb2c2a4) entered blocking state
Mar 12 10:43:45 machine1 kernel: docker_gwbridge: port 4(vethcb2c2a4) entered disabled state
Mar 12 10:43:45 machine1 kernel: device vethcb2c2a4 entered promiscuous mode
Mar 12 10:43:45 machine1 systemd-udevd[2887]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for vethc361b7b: No such file or directory
Mar 12 10:43:45 machine1 systemd-udevd[2890]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Mar 12 10:43:45 machine1 systemd-udevd[2890]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for veth7574e8b: No such file or directory
Mar 12 10:43:45 machine1 kernel: veth2: renamed from veth6691f49
Mar 12 10:43:45 machine1 kernel: br0: port 4(veth2) entered blocking state
Mar 12 10:43:45 machine1 kernel: br0: port 4(veth2) entered disabled state
Mar 12 10:43:45 machine1 kernel: device veth2 entered promiscuous mode
Mar 12 10:43:45 machine1 kernel: br0: port 4(veth2) entered blocking state
Mar 12 10:43:45 machine1 kernel: br0: port 4(veth2) entered forwarding state
Mar 12 10:43:45 machine1 systemd-udevd[2937]: link_config: could not get ethtool features for vethbf19a70
Mar 12 10:43:45 machine1 systemd-udevd[2937]: Could not set offload features of vethbf19a70: No such device
Mar 12 10:43:45 machine1 systemd-udevd[2889]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Mar 12 10:43:45 machine1 systemd-udevd[2891]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Mar 12 10:43:45 machine1 systemd-udevd[2891]: link_config: could not get ethtool features for veth3b5a70d
Mar 12 10:43:45 machine1 systemd-udevd[2891]: Could not set offload features of veth3b5a70d: No such device
Mar 12 10:43:45 machine1 systemd-udevd[2885]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Mar 12 10:43:45 machine1 systemd-udevd[2885]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for veth2100695: No such file or directory
Mar 12 10:43:45 machine1 systemd-udevd[2884]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
```

Comment: i think i found problem, My memcached service on worker node taken too much memory and to make room for more data it started stoping other services.